# Configure an IPv6 tunnel to use its routed IPv6 network

Tags: routing, ipv6, tunnel

When creating an IPv6 tunnel with tunnelbroker.net, the Tunnel Broker service assigns you a client IPv6 address to be used on the router and a routed IPv6 network to be used by the systems in the network.

However, I don't have a network: I have a single system with IPv4 connectivity, to whom I'd like to also give IPv6 connectivity. I can easily configure the tunnel using the client IPv6 address (the Tunnel Broker service also has configuration examples), and that's already enough for sending IPv6 traffic.

That's not ideal, though: I am using the client IPv6 address, which would only be meant to be used for the tunnel, as my IPv6 traffic origin address. On a more practical side, I cannot configure rDNS resolution for that address, which for example impairs my ability to send email through SMTP.

What I would like is to have my IPv6 traffic sent as if it was originating from an address in the routed IPv6 network, even though the host sending the traffic and the router forwarding it though the tunnel are actually the same system. Is there a reasonable way to configure a standard Linux (Debian) system to act like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can literally just have both addresses on the same machine; there is no requirement for the routed /64 to be used somewhere else.

1. Configure the client address with a "preferred lifetime" of 0 (e.g. `preferred_lft 0` in an iproute2 command), so that it will not be chosen for outbound packets if another address is available, while still accepting inbound ones.
2. Then configure any address from your routed /64 or /48 on any interface. (For example, assign an 2001:470:foo::1/128 to the same tunnel interface, or to `lo`, or to dummy0.)

Even in normal usage with a network, "the router" and "systems in the network" overlap – the router has an IP address from each network that it is connected to, and is free to use any of its addresses to send traffic through any interface.

For example, if you were to use the 2001:foo::/64 for a real network on eth0, then you would almost always assign eth0 itself an address from that network (such as 2001:foo::1/64), and the router could use that address to originate packets from sit0. The above instructions aren't any different from that.

---

Technically, as this is a point-to-point L3 tunnel (with only one endpoint and no L2 addressing), you wouldn't need to assign the "client" address *at all* – a router's address is never involved in sending forwarded packets, only receiving, and with PtP tunnels you would still receive the packets just by being on the other end of the tunnel. (Only with link types that use ARP/NDP, such as Ethernet or L2 tunnels that emulate it, would the address be required in order to have prefixes routed to you.)

(Similarly, for outgoing packets through L3 tunnels, the "server address" is not really used as there are no NDP lookups – just routing via `dev sit0` will get the packets to the other end of the link anyway.)

However, with HE.NET tunnels, you still need to keep the "client" address for another reason – periodic idle checks which will disable the tunnel if the client does not reply to pings for several months.

Comment: I am not using an HE tunnel, this is a /56 from my ISP. I don't understand your reply. The host and VM can share the same address? I didn't understand your reply.